# cannot find module "token" discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

trying to figure out what i have done wrong here i have definitely installed the correct directories. keeps picking my token up as an error module.

below is the error and below that is the code itself if anyone could help much appreciated can't find anything on google about a token module error.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mytokencode'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\user\Desktop\HogwartsBot\index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1020:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:890:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1080:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\user\Desktop\HogwartsBot\index.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1196:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:929:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\HogwartsBot\\index.js' ]
}
```

code ran

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const path = require('path');
const oneLine = require('common-tags').oneLine;
const sqlite = require('sqlite');
const token = require('mytokencode').token;

const client = new commando.Client({
    owner: '184191493919997952',
    commandPrefix: '>>'
});

bot.login(mytokencode)

client
    .on('error', console.error)
    .on('warn', console.warn)
    .on('debug', console.log)
    .on('ready', () => {
        console.log(`Client ready; logged in as ${client.user.username}#${client.user.discriminator} (${client.user.id})`);
    })
    .on('disconnect', () => { console.warn('Disconnected!'); })
    .on('reconnecting', () => { console.warn('Reconnecting...'); })
    .on('commandError', (cmd, err) => {
        if(err instanceof commando.FriendlyError) return;
        console.error(`Error in command ${cmd.groupID}:${cmd.memberName}`, err);
    })
    .on('commandBlocked', (msg, reason) => {
        console.log(oneLine`
            Command ${msg.command ? `${msg.command.groupID}:${msg.command.memberName}` : ''}
            blocked; ${reason}
        `);
    })
    .on('commandPrefixChange', (guild, prefix) => {
        console.log(oneLine`
            Prefix ${prefix === '' ? 'removed' : `changed to ${prefix || 'the default'}`}
            ${guild ? `in guild ${guild.name} (${guild.id})` : 'globally'}.
        `);
    })
    .on('commandStatusChange', (guild, command, enabled) => {
        console.log(oneLine`
            Command ${command.groupID}:${command.memberName}
            ${enabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}
            ${guild ? `in guild ${guild.name} (${guild.id})` : 'globally'}.
        `);
    })
    .on('groupStatusChange', (guild, group, enabled) => {
        console.log(oneLine`
            Group ${group.id}
            ${enabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}
            ${guild ? `in guild ${guild.name} (${guild.id})` : 'globally'}.
        `);
    });

client.setProvider(
    sqlite.open(path.join(__dirname, 'database.sqlite3')).then(db => new commando.SQLiteProvider(db))
).catch(console.error);

client.registry
    .registerGroup('basic', 'Basic')
    .registerDefaults()
    .registerTypesIn(path.join(__dirname, 'types'))
    .registerCommandsIn(path.join(__dirname, 'commands'));

client.login('mytokencode');
```

cant seem to figure out what i have done wrong

*notes* 
i am new to this :P might be a rookie mistake

Comment: ```mytokencode``` is a file you made yourself, and not a node package, I believe, so you have to require it as ```require('./mytokencode')```.

Answer (score 0):

`mytokencode` is a file you made yourself, and not a node package, I believe, so you have to require it as `require('./mytokencode')`.

Also, `bot.login(mytokencode)` should be replaced by `client.login(token)` since you stored the token in the `token` variable and your Bot is in the `client` object.

Also, the last line of the code `client.login('mytokencode')` will not be required since you will have already called `client.login(token)` before.

Comment: ive corrected ```const token = require('./NysTISNzRaotd6EjJaTzF86FkeSpmjqh').token;``` and am recieving the same error. i changed the bot.login to client and deleted the one at the bottom

Comment: Are you sure that you are storing your token in a file named ```NysTISNzRaotd6EjJaTzF86FkeSpmjqh.js``` in the same directory as this bot code?

Comment: would you know how to define that in the NysTISNzRaotd6EjJaTzF86FkeSpmjqh.js

Comment: sorry im so fresh at this

Comment: Ok so i'd suggest a simple way. Create a file called token.js containing 
```module.exports = <your token here>```
Then in your bot code, simply do ```const token = require('./token.js');```

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '../../src'
is the new error so it did change PROGRESS!

Comment: oh and SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Well i mean your token should be a string

Comment: module.exports = 'Aschquywhdi378dniuahsa.sdiuqhnwdihqnwdu.awiudhiywd';

Comment: wait facepalm is it just token without < > lmaooo

Comment: Something like this

Comment: okay now it just doesnt like the src ```Error: Cannot find module '../../src```

Comment: Ok its another require error so you have to put in the path appropriately

Answer (score 0):

It will be more safe to place it in env file. (And get it using `process.env.TOKEN`)

Comment: ooOo how do i do that

Comment: Based on hosting, if you are using something as glitch, there is already .env file, else you need to install dotenv package and require and config it in the code, there are really tons of tutorials. And also, I found, that it is not more safe by default, but most hostings have this file more safe (as for example glitch).